# Inserting new records into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, adventureworks

I'm still new here and even in Visual Studio so I don't fully know all the function in Visual Studio. I'm trying to insert data into SQL Server. When I run this code and enter the necessary information, my label message will show up, but when I look in SQL Server, nothing has changed. Visual Studio is connected to SQL Server. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class NewEmployee : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
        {
            Label14.Text = ("**Your data has been entered in SQL"); 
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection vid = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JOSAN;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=True");
        {
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("Insert into HumanResources.Employee(NationalIDNumber, LoginID, JobTitle, BirthDate, MaritalStatus, Gender, HireDate, SalariedFlag, VacationHours, SickLeaveHours, CurrentFlag, ModifiedDate) Values(@NationalIDNumber, @loginID, @JobTitle, @BirthDate, @MaritalStatus, @Gender, @HireDate, @SalariedFlag, @VacationHours, @SickLeaveHours, @CurrentFlag, @ModifiedDate)", vid); 
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalIDNumber", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text));
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", TextBox2.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", TextBox3.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text));
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", Convert.ToChar(TextBox5.Text));
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Convert.ToChar(TextBox6.Text));
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HireDate", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox7.Text));
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalariedFlag", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox8.Text));
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VacationHours", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox9.Text));
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SickLeaveHours", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox10.Text));
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentFlag", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox11.Text));
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedDate", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox12.Text));

            try
            {
                vid.Open();
                xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                vid.Close();
            }

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                TextBox2.Text = "";
                TextBox3.Text = "";
                TextBox4.Text = "";
                TextBox5.Text = "";
                TextBox6.Text = "";
                TextBox7.Text = "";
                TextBox8.Text = "";
                TextBox9.Text = "";
                TextBox10.Text = "";
                TextBox11.Text = "";
                TextBox12.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your command work on your sql server? What are your column types exactly? How about try to add your paramters with `Add` method and specify it's type and size? [`AddWihValue` _might_ generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) And use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

Comment: Have you tried running the query through either ssms or sqlcmd? Did it work then, do nothing or give an error message?

Comment: `1.Use transactions and exception handling`       `2.Use Sql Profiler to trace your values sent to SQL Server`

Comment: ExecuteNotQuery() returns int with rows affected. might be worth checking it to help you in debugging.

Comment: You close your connection in the catch block so there no exception so your connection is not closed. Try to close in finally block

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using(SqlConnection vid = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JOSAN;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using(SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand())
    {
        xp.CommandText = @"Insert into HumanResources.Employee(NationalIDNumber, LoginID, JobTitle, BirthDate, MaritalStatus, Gender, HireDate, SalariedFlag, VacationHours, SickLeaveHours, CurrentFlag, ModifiedDate) Values(@NationalIDNumber, @loginID, @JobTitle, @BirthDate, @MaritalStatus, @Gender, @HireDate, @SalariedFlag, @VacationHours, @SickLeaveHours, @CurrentFlag, @ModifiedDate)"; 
        xp.Connection = vid;
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalIDNumber", TextBox1.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", TextBox2.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", TextBox3.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", TextBox4.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", Convert.ToChar(TextBox5.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", TextBox6.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HireDate", TextBox7.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalariedFlag", TextBox8.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VacationHours", TextBox9.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SickLeaveHours", TextBox10.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentFlag", TextBox11.Text);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedDate", TextBox12.Text);
        try
        {
            vid.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessgeBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error Message");
            vid.Close();
        }
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            TextBox2.Text = "";
            TextBox3.Text = "";
            TextBox4.Text = "";
            TextBox5.Text = "";
            TextBox6.Text = "";
            TextBox7.Text = "";
            TextBox8.Text = "";
            TextBox9.Text = "";
            TextBox10.Text = "";
            TextBox11.Text = "";
            TextBox12.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You can use implicit casting `AddWithValue` and change the statement like this

```
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalIDNumber", TextBox1.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", TextBox2.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", TextBox3.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", TextBox4.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", Convert.ToChar(TextBox5.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", TextBox6.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HireDate", TextBox7.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalariedFlag", TextBox8.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VacationHours", TextBox9.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SickLeaveHours", TextBox10.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentFlag", TextBox11.Text);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedDate", TextBox12.Text);
```

Comment: Why do you think using verbatim string on command will change something? It doesn't _even_ include any escape character.

Comment: @SonerGönül: Thanks for notifying. Let me change it